# Task.Delay not returning to main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I am testing out async/await and here is the problem. I am starting two tasks asynchronously and waiting for their execution to complete. I expect the two tasks to wait for respective delays and then return to print total milliseconds elapsed. But the program is only printing `1 start " + current time` and `2 start " + current time` but nothing after that. How can I return from the delayed tasks and print the final result?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunTasksWithDelays();
    }

    static async void RunTasksWithDelays()
    {
        Stopwatch s = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Task task1 = LongRunningTask1();
        Task task2 = LongRunningTask2();

        await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
        Console.WriteLine("total milliseconds elapsed:  " + s.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000);

    }

    static async Task LongRunningTask1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1 start " + DateTime.Now);
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine("1 end " + DateTime.Now);

    }

    static async Task LongRunningTask2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2 start " + DateTime.Now);
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine("2 end " + DateTime.Now);

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main thread ends and thus program ends because there is no foreground thread in your application to keep the program alive.

Ideally you should be awaiting `RunTasksWithDelays` method but you can't await it for two reasons

1. Your method doesn't return `Task`
2. `Main` method doesn't support `await`.

You should make the RunTasksWithDelays method return `async Task` rather than `async void` and you should wait for its completion. Waiting synchronously is a bad idea, that's fine in this scenario as we don't have any choices.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RunTasksWithDelays().Wait();
}

static async Task RunTasksWithDelays()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This works. I knew I needed to await but didn't know how to do it inside Main.

Comment: Is there a way of knowing how many threads were spawned during the complete execution?

Comment: @Sam No, there is not. Operation could have completed without any singe thread or N number of threads. There is no way to find out(AFAIK).

Answer (score 2):

Your method `RunTasksWithDelays` should return a Task for the caller to wait for this task to complete.

Then you can simply call `RunTasksWithDelays().Wait();`

Comment: `RunTasksWithDelays` is a void method.

Comment: Good catch, I saw the async keyword and my brain inserted Task.